CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE not settable?
clock_gettime(clockid_t clockid, struct timespec *tp);
clockid CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE:
A faster but less precise version of CLOCK_REALTIME.  This clock is not settable. ...
But if I adjust CLOCK_REALTIME does CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE adopts these changes? I mean it is still a realtime (wall time) clock - just faster (vdso) to the detriment of accuracy, isn't it?

I looked at https://lwn.net/Articles/347811/ and Do CLOCK_MONOTONIC and CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE have the same base? and https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=fb7fcc96a86cfaef0f6dcc0665516aa68611e736  :

CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE not settable?

Yes.

f I adjust CLOCK_REALTIME does CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE adopts these changes?

Yes.

I mean it is still a realtime (wall time) clock - just faster (vdso) to the detriment of accuracy, isn't it?

And is less accurate (is older), as it returns the last tick from the last time the kernel updated some internal structure.

thank you, confirms my assumption. I use a lot of timestamps but am satisfied with an accuracy of a few ms. So it fits.
